# PHP _REQUEST redirect?

Tags: php, request

I am reading a script but am stuck on understanding this:

```
$redirect = base64_decode($_REQUEST['redirect']);
header("Location:$redirect");exit;
```

because the redirect variable in REQUEST isn't defined anywhere in the script. Prior to this a POST form has been filled in, but there is NO mention of the redirect variable anywhere in the script so I am confused how it is not empty...

EDIT:

here's the form code below. btw like I said, the word 'redirect' doesn't appear ANYWHERE in the script, which is what is confusing me.

```
        <form name="login" action="{$baseurl}/login" method="post">
            {$lang12}
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            {$lang11}
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="{$lang18}" />
            <div class="test"><a href="{$baseurl}/signup"><b>{$lang30}</b></a> - <a href="{$baseurl}/password">{$lang19}</a></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="authenticate" value="1" />
        </form>
        </div>
```

The $lang stuff is commonly appearing words from an array, e.g login, etc.

Comment: Post a link to the full script, please.

Answer (score 1):

> #### $_REQUEST
>
> An associative array that by default
> contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST`
> and `$_COOKIE`.

So if you have `$_POST['redirect']`, `$_GET['redirect']` or `$_COOKIE['redirect']`, `$_REQUEST['redirect']` will be defined. Try to put:

```
var_dump($_POST['redirect']);
var_dump($_GET['redirect']);
var_dump($_COOKIE['redirect']);
```

To find out where it's coming from.

Comment: I'm talking about the redirect variable in the request array. How is that always defined? And what is it's initial value if so?

Comment: $_REQUEST['redirect'] should not be defined not that $_REQUEST should not be defined.

Comment: David we need to see your form's markup in order to debug your issue

Comment: I have updated the question.

I will attempt the var dump

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible to answer for certain without seeing the actual code but [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) holds all the variables in `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

A form can actually populate both `$_GET` and `$_POST` if its method is set to 'post' and its action is a url with url encoded variables. Thus the form might be posting all of its data to a url and then adding get variables to the end of that url. For example:

```
<form method='post' action='example.php?var=test'>
    <input name='var2' id='var2' />
</form>
```

If that form were submitted, the following would be defined: `$_POST['var2'], $_GET['var'], $_REQUEST['var2'], $_REQUEST['var']`.

`$_COOKIE` could also be putting hidden variables in $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

it have so much possibility that the redirect variable is a cookies. if you cannot find it at the form.

```
var_dump($_REGISTER);
```

that will list all your input variable associated with POST, GET and COOKIES.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not empty what's the content of it?

I think it should be something like this...

```
$redirect = base64_decode($_GET['redirect']);
if(!empty($redirect){
header("Location: $redirect");
exit;
}
```

It doesn't matter that it's not in the script, you can set it via GET,
eg /yourform.php?redirect=index.php

Is it causing unwanted redirection?